# Showing numbers with 2 odd numbers that also contain 4 and 5 up to 10 000 in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, count

I'm trying to make a program that will only show numbers with 2 odd numbers that also contain a 4 and a 5 up to 10000.

I made this but i can't get it to check the odd number, it only shows the ones that contain a 4 and a 5.

```
n = 9999
def countNumbersWith4(n) : 
    result = 0
    for x in range(1, n + 1) : 
        if((has4(x) == True) & (has5(x) == True)) :
            def countEvenOdd(x):
                odd_count = 0
                while (x > 0):
                    rem = x % 10
                    if (rem % 2 != 0):
                        odd_count += 1             
                    x = int(x / 10)
            t = countEvenOdd(x);
            result = result + 1 
            print(x)
    return result 
def has4(x) : 
    while (x != 0) : 
        if (x%10 == 4) : 
            return True 
        x = x //10
def has5(x) :
    while (x != 0) :
        if (x%10 == 5) :
            return True
        x = x //10 

    return False
print ("0 to ", n," is ",countNumbersWith4(n))
```

Comment: do you want all numbers or just the amount of numbers that match this? and just to check if I got it right, you want to count numbers like 453?

Comment: I needed the actual list of numbers not the total amount

Comment: oh sorry i forgot one thing only number with 4 digits but even with all of them its fine

Comment: An example of the output would be like 1425 something that contains 2 odd numbers and also contains a 4 and a 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not the best style maybe but works, hope also for you ;-)

```
def two_odd_numbers(n):
    cnt = 0

    for i in n:
        if int(i) % 2 == 0:
            cnt += 1

    return cnt == 2

def containing_two_odd_numbers_4_and_5(n):
    l = []
    for i in range(1000, n):
        number = str(i)
        if '4' in number and '5' in number and two_odd_numbers(number):
            l.append(i)
    return l


if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = 9999
    l = containing_two_odd_numbers_4_and_5(n)
    print('0 to {} is {}'.format(n, len(l)))
    print(l)
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me really means a lot :)

Comment: that's why we are here

Comment: Can't you just use the `in` keyword to see if a digit is in a number. `contains()` would simplify to `return str(c) in n`

Answer (score 0):

This function can be passed any range of numbers you like, I just set the minimum at 455 as that is the lowest valid number to save some computing time, because I am packing it into a set, the output is out of order, so I sort it

```
def findnumber(n):
    result = set()
    for x in range(455, n):
        odds = 0
        fours = 0
        fives = 0
        i = x
        j = x % 10
        while i:
            if j == 4:   fours += 1
            if j == 5:   fives += 1
            if j % 2:    odds += 1
            j = i % 10
            i //= 10

        if odds == 2 and fours == 1 and fives == 1:
            result.add(x)
    return result

N = 99999
print("0 to ", N, " is ", sorted(findnumber(N))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dirty solution using regex and the `re` module, which returns a `bool`:

```
import re

def has2Odd4and5(x):
    return re.match(r'(((4.*5)|(5.*4)).*[13579])|(((4.*[13579])|([13579].*4)).*5)|((([13579].*5)|(5.*[13579])).*4)', str(x)) is not None
```

Example Usage:

```
>>> print(filter(has2Odd4and5,range(1000,10000))
[1045, 1054, 1145, 1154, 1245, 1254, 1345, 1354, 1405, ...
```

I'm sure this regex could be simplified even further